# SQL: Syntax error during loop for varchar field (Account Numbers) which are solely numerics

Tags: sql-server, loops, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to create multiple tables from 1 large dataset using an account #. I am attempting a loop in order to not have to manual update the criteria (over 40 accounts). The loop works, but only partially. Apparently there are some account #'s which look like numbers (e.g. 123456), while most have some combination of alphabet and numbers (e.g.) AB1CD2. The latter account numbers flow through just fine, but I receive a syntax error (Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1) for all the other accounts in my table. The account field (shipper) is already a varchar. Here is the sample of the query below:

```
DECLARE ABCAccounts CURSOR
GLOBAL
FOR SELECT DISTINCT Shipper FROM dbo.ABCCompany
OPEN ABCAccounts

DECLARE @Shipper varchar(6)

FETCH NEXT FROM ABCAccounts INTO @Shipper
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

DECLARE @Maketable varchar(1000)
SELECT @Maketable=
'SELECT TOP 1000 * 
INTO '+@Shipper+' 
FROM [dbo].[ABCCompany]
WHERE Shipper='''+@Shipper+''''
EXEC (@Maketable)

FETCH NEXT FROM ABCAccounts INTO @Shipper

END

CLOSE ABCAccounts
```

I don't know enough about SQL data types to know if I can work around this or not. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: slightly off topic but you are using top without an order by. Do you not care which 1000 rows get into all these tables? Also, what happens when one of those tables already exists because this ran previously?

Comment: The main table contains millions of records, so I just wanted to take a smaller amount to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is SQL Server, this should work:

```
'SELECT TOP 1000 * 
INTO ['+@Shipper+'] 
FROM [dbo].[ABCCompany]
WHERE Shipper='''+@Shipper+''''
```

If you use special characters or start with numbers you'll have to enclose the names into [].

Comment: This was it! Awesome! Glad it was so simple